# UNION returns incomplete result

Tags: ms-access

***preface***

I have 2 tables:

- 'MacroAttività'
- 'Tags'

Each MacroAttività record has more than 1 tag to be identified so I need multiple parameter for querying with the selected tags. The only method I thought is writing multiple queries on the same table and unify the results. The proble is that Access doesn't return me all the records with the tags I specified. Here 's the statement:

```
SELECT MacroAttività.[Nome/Descrizione], MacroAttività.Descrizione,MacroAttività.Leader, MacroAttività.[Data inizio attività], MacroAttività.[Data fine prevista], MacroAttività.[Data fine effettiva], MacroAttività.Note
FROM MacroAttività INNER JOIN Tags ON MacroAttività.ID = Tags.[ID macro attività]
WHERE (((Tags.Tag)=[input tag1]))
UNION SELECT MacroAttività.[Nome/Descrizione], MacroAttività.Descrizione, MacroAttività.Leader, MacroAttività.[Data inizio attività], MacroAttività.[Data fine prevista], MacroAttività.[Data fine effettiva], MacroAttività.Note
FROM MacroAttività INNER JOIN Tags ON MacroAttività.ID = Tags.[ID macro attività]
WHERE (((Tags.Tag)=[input tag 1]));
```

For example I have on record 1 of 'MacroAttività' the tag 'test' and on record 2 the tag 'white'. When querying both tags into the forms 'input tag1' and 'input tag 2' it returns me just the record 1 and not record 2. What did I mistake?

Comment: `UNION` filters the duplicates. use `UNION ALL` to keep all records. Try this

Comment: Now it gives me only empty rows, numerically exact but all empty.

Comment: Then something else is going on.

Comment: fixed. Actually Thomas G gave me the answer, if he writes it I'll upscore it.

Comment: Why don't you do `WHERE (Tags.Tag=[input tag1]) OR (Tags.Tag=[input tag2])` etc. ?

Comment: @Andre: because they wouldn't get duplicates? Bizarrely, the OP *wants* duplicates!